# String with emoticon appears to be valid UTF-8 but iconv cannot handle it

Tags: php, utf-8, iconv, ucs2

I've got the following code that tries to encode a UTF-8 string to UCS-2LE. The string appears to be valid, as can be checked with `mb_check_encoding`, however when I run `iconv` on it, I get the following notice:

> Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string

Any idea what the issue is?

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$string = 'Voiture ';
$isValidUTF8 = mb_check_encoding($string, 'UTF-8');
echo 'Is valid UTF-8: ' . ($isValidUTF8 ? 'Yes' : 'No') . "\n";

$text1 = iconv('UTF-8', 'UCS-2LE', $string);
var_dump($text1);
```

**Output:**

> Is valid UTF-8: Yes
>
> Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string
>
> bool(false)

Comment: Try Ignore parameter. Let me know if you get any other solution

Comment: I know about the ignore option but I'd rather find a way to convert, if it can be done

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that  isn't a valid *UCS-2LE* character. You could try to append `\TRANSLIT` or `\IGNORE` to the output encoding.

Using TRANSLIT should replace non existing characters with similar ones and IGNORE removes them from the output string.

You could do this like that, but thats not tested, and I'm not sure, if this works with UCS-2LE

```
$text1 = iconv('UTF-8', 'UCS-2LE\\IGNORE', $string);
// or
$text1 = iconv('UTF-8', 'UCS-2LE\\TRANSLIT', $string);
```

If you need emoji support, you should think about stay at the UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. Of course the input characters are not valid ucs-2cs since they are utf-8, and the point of iconv is to convert a string into another. In this case the input is valid utf-8, at least according to the earlier check.

Comment: @this.lau_ since your emoji isn't in the character table of UCS-2LE, you simply can't convert it to UCS-2LE.